# Issue accessing object on mouseover in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working with the `threex domevents` by `Jeromeetienne`: https://github.com/jeromeetienne/threex.domevents to handle my hover over of `rendered in` objects in my `canvas`

I am having some issue when updating the perspective view when the user changes the type of object, my `dom` sets the `event listener` but it seems to never get called.  Here is the overview:

When user first loads the page, we set our camera:

```
       // setup local vars
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40,window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,1,10000);
        camera.position.set(500, 800, 1300);// 1st = swing (left or right) 2nd = up or down 3rd = zoom
        camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3());
        camera.positionID = 1;// default
        camera.positionType = 'sideView';// default
        this.cam = camera;
```

Than we set our `renderer`:

```
        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColor( 0xf0f0f0 );
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
```

Now when a user clicks the canvas, an object is added.  We first get our positioning and call a `intersectofobjects` to see if we are actually on the canvas `(mousedown)`:

```
          event.preventDefault();
          this.mouse.x = ( event.clientX / this.renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
          this.mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / this.renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;

          this.raycaster.setFromCamera( this.mouse, this.camera.cam );
          var intersects = this.raycaster.intersectObjects( this.blocks );
```

After we actually figure out that we are on the plane, we setup our object:

```
         var voxel = new THREE.Mesh( this.room.cubeGeometry.clone(), this.room.cubeMaterial.clone() );
         voxel.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
         voxel.position.copy( intersect.point ).add( intersect.face.normal );
         voxel.position.divideScalar( this.room.divideScalar ).floor().multiplyScalar( this.room.multiplyScalar ).addScalar( this.room.addScalar );
```

After we setup our object we setup the `event listeners on the object`

```
        // get our dom event to attach to object
        var domEvents   = new THREEx.DomEvents(this.camera.cam, this.renderer.domElement);
        // DOM events for inside 3d rendering
        domEvents.addEventListener(voxel, 'mouseover', this.onDocumentMouseOverCube.bind(this),false);
        domEvents.addEventListener(voxel, 'mouseout', this.onDocumentMouseOutCube.bind(this),false);

        this.scene.add( voxel );
        this.blocks.push( voxel );
        this.rooms.push(voxel);

        this.render();
```

This works perfect on first use.  It only seems to stop working when the user changes the `object` that they want to place on the screen, here is how.

We have a `gui` object that handles our connection with the `UI` and the `core`, when someone chooses to add a different object, we call:

```
        jQuery(".changeRoomType.active").removeClass('active');
        jQuery(event.srcElement).toggleClass('active');
        this.canvas.room.updateRoomType(event.srcElement.id);
```

Now when `room.updateRoomType...()` is called it initiates an object like this:

```
        var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 100, 50, 100,2,1,2 );// moving to roomObj
        var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x00ff80,overdraw: 1 } ); // moving to roomObj
        var cubeTmpHoverMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x00ff80, transparent: true, overdraw: 0, opacity:0.5});// used to give a transparency to the cube tmp view // moving to roomObj
        var divideScalar = 50; 
        var multiplyScalar = 50;
        var addScalar = 25;
        var additionalZ = 25;
        var additionalX = 25;



        this.divideScalar = divideScalar;
        this.multiplyScalar = multiplyScalar;
        this.addScalar = addScalar;

        var colorNormal = 0x00ff80;
        var colorHover = 0xE4E4E4;
        var colorTmpHover = 0xEAEAEA;
        var colorRemove = 0xE23434;

        this.colorNormal = colorNormal;
        this.colorHover = colorHover;
        this.colorTmpHover = colorTmpHover;
        this.colorRemove = colorRemove;

        this.additionalZ = additionalZ;
        this.additionalX = additionalX;

        this.cubeGeometry = cubeGeometry;
        this.cubeMaterial = cubeMaterial;
        this.cubeTmpHoverMaterial = cubeTmpHoverMaterial;
```

Now after this point the `mouseover` and `mouseout` on the object seem to never work anymore.  My question is why is this?  Am I not updating my `camera perspective` after changing the object type to be displayed?

EDIT:

Please note that our initiated object that is first selected on page load is the following:

```
            var cubeGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 50, 50, 50,1,1,1 );// moving to roomObj
            var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: 0x00ff80, overdraw: 1 } ); // moving to roomObj
            var cubeTmpHoverMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({ color: 0x00ff80, transparent: true, overdraw: 0,opacity:0.5});// used to give a transparency to the cube tmp view // moving to roomObj
            var divideScalar = 50; 
            var multiplyScalar = 50;
            var addScalar = 25;

            var additionalZ = 0;
            var additionalX = 0;
            this.additionalZ = additionalZ;
            this.additionalX = additionalX;

            var colorNormal = 0x00ff80;
            var colorHover = 0xE4E4E4;
            var colorTmpHover = 0xEAEAEA;
            var colorRemove = 0xE23434;

            this.colorNormal = colorNormal;
            this.colorHover = colorHover;
            this.colorTmpHover = colorTmpHover;
            this.colorRemove = colorRemove;

            this.cubeGeometry = cubeGeometry;
            this.cubeMaterial = cubeMaterial;
            this.cubeTmpHoverMaterial = cubeTmpHoverMaterial;
```

The other object that was called above shown in the original question demonstrates our other object size.  After this is called it seems to stop recognizing the location of our `mouseover` and `mouseout` on the object and or its being placed on someplace else it should not be.

Comment: Are you calling ```var domEvents   = new THREEx.DomEvents(this.camera.cam, this.renderer.domElement);``` on every object created? You are supposed to only do it once.

Comment: Falk I am now. I was calling it every time.